# I couldn't pass the variable in the data display code to another database code(this connects with the databse)

Tags: php, mysql

I retrieve data from the database and present some data in text boxes, so that user can edit them. But there are multiple rows that user can edit. In order to get the number of records present to the user, I have used a variable called count. But I cant use that variable in the php database code.

**part of data display code**

```
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                        echo '<form action = "UpdateItem.php" method="post">';
                        echo "<tr>";

                            echo "<td>" . $row['item_id'] . "</td>"; echo"<td ></td>";
                            $id[] = $row['item_id'];

                            echo "<td>" . $row['buyingPrice'] . "</td>";echo"<td></td>";
                            $sellingPrice = $row['sellingPrice'];
                            echo "<td>"."<input type ='text' name = \"sellingPrice".$count."\" value ='".$sellingPrice."'>"."</td>";
                            $stockQty = $row['stockQty'];
                            echo "<td>"."<input type ='text' name = \"stockQty".$count."\" value ='".$stockQty."'>"."</td>";
                            $count = $count + 1;
                     echo "</td>";
                        echo "</tr>";                     
                    }

                    echo "</table>";
                    ?>
                    <div id="">
                    <input type="submit" class="myButton" id="btnManageStockUpdate" name="btnManageStockUpdate" value="Update"  />
                    </div>

                    <?php

                    echo "</form>";
```

**php database code**

```
           echo ("SellingPrice".$x);
            $sellingPrice = $_POST['sellingPrice'.$x];

            $stockQty = $_POST['stockQty'.$x];                

            $sql = "UPDATE item SET sellingPrice = $sellingPrice,stockQty = $stockQty WHERE item_id = $id[$x]";
            $result = mysqli_query($dbcon,$sql);
} 
 }
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a hidden input field with name count and pass your count variable to it

```
<input type="hidden" value="<?php $count?>" name="count">
```

so at the end of the loop it will store the final count which you can use it to iterate a for loop in your php database code.